# NUnit step in TeamCity tries to run tests against business logic .dlls because they're in the same folder as my test .dlls

Tags: nunit, teamcity

I'm setting up a CI server for my company and integrating Unit Testing. I've chosen to use TeamCity and NUnit, as they've worked well for other organizations I've worked for in the past.

I have TeamCity up and running and I've created just a test Unit Test project for now so I can verify that TC is handling my NUnit configuration properly.

My solution file contains 6 C# projects, one VB.NET project and one unmanaged c++ project. For each of those (where required) there is one separate C# project that houses the test cases for the associated project, and contains a reference to that project.

When the NUnit step runs and finds .dlls where I've told it to look, it complains that the .dll files are not the right architecture, not the right .NET version, not the right alignment of the stars etc... This is because it's trying to run NUnit against business logic .dll files, as they're built and output from the test project along with the test .dll. The test .dll file is the correct architecture, .NET version etc... as is required by NUnit.

My question is this:

How can I tell TeamCity to either

1. Not care if the .dll file is the correct architecture, just skip it if it isn't
2. Only look for the proper .dlls

I've tried to keep just a folder called Test Dlls at my root, but I can't figure out how to get every project to *only* put the test .dll file there.

Lastly, I will be having my coworkers generating their own unit tests for their solution files, which are not of the same layout and configuration as I described above. I *really* don't want to have to tell my coworkers to name their files a certain way, or set their projects to build in a particular fashion etc... if at all avoidable.

Comment: Have you tried entering a filter in the 'Run Tests From' field? You can use this to filter the dlls which are searched for Tests.

Comment: Yes I have. The only place to look for the test .dll file is in the bin/Release folder, where all the Business logic's .dlls get built to as well.

Comment: You could filter on individual files in there. E.g. /bin/Release/*.Test.dll

Comment: Yeah I did think about that but as I mentioned, that would require me to tell other people to be sure that their Unit Test projects are named a certain way. I guess it's not the worst thing in the world, but the hit-by-a-bus scenario leaves my successor without any knowledge of why new Unit Tests aren't working properly.

Comment: Your team can't agree to name all projects that contain unit tests according to some convention? That doesn't seem like too much to ask.

Comment: There were no answers to this question so I never got a chance to accept an answer. @PollyShaw I ended up using your solution and telling everyone to conform. If you want the rep, I'll accept the answer if you post one.

Comment: Well I did sort of miss the point of the question so I don't think I should. And I think there may be a better and more fiddly answer - e.g. write a custom build step which inspects all the dlls to see if they contain tests and then passes them to the NUnit command line if they do.